# Yelp android studio VALIDATION_ERROR

Tags: java, android, postman, yelp, yelp-fusion-api

I am trying to integrate the YELP API within an application in Android Studio. I am trying to acquire an access token using a post request in Postman. However, when I send the post request I get this error returned in JSON format:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "description": "'client_credentials' is not one of ['authorization_code', 'refresh_token']",
    "field": "grant_type",
    "instance": "client_credentials"
   }
}
```

I have searched this site and google for what the description line means in particular:

```
"description": "'client_credentials' is not one of ['authorization_code', 'refresh_token']",
```

I have  not been able to find any results as to what this error means. Here is my project setup in postman:

[image]

I simply copy and pasted my client ID and API key from yelp and stored them within the client_id and client_secret in Postman respectively. When I send this requestion I get the 400 Bad Request error and find out that its a validation error. At first I thought that I entered the wrong API key, however, I refreshed the API key and directly copy and pasted it, so I am confident that my API key and client ID are correct. The output should look like this and it should deliver an access token:

[image]

I couldn't find any examples that had this specific error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no longer need a refresh token, all you need is an API key in your Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer {{apiKey}}
```

Source: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/authentication

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that the documentation shows no way to do this in Postman. That's where I'm kind of lost at this point. I have no clue where to type in "Authorization: Bearer {{apikey}} because all of the data that I saw online only shows  how to do it when you needed a refresh token. I can't find any examples of doing this in Postman to get the access token.

Comment: I was able to figure it out in POSTMAN. Under Bearer Token I simply added the API key as the token. Thanks for the help. That put me on the right path and saved the day.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo - can you post the screenshot of your solution?